# Mobile program to access a web service

Tags: java, xml, web-services, java-me

I'm trying to create a program which needs to access a web service. E.g. a mobile program that accesses a a super market service. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Web Services API (JSR 172)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=172) will allow you to connect to a remote web service from a  J2ME application.